# Pandas - Add Column Name to Results of groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to add column names to the results of a groupby on a `DataFrame` in Python 3.6.

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'timeIndex': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'isZero': [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df2 = df.groupby(['timeIndex'])['isZero'].sum()
print(df2)
```

Result

```
timeIndex
1    1
2    0
Name: isZero, dtype: int64
```

It looks like `timeIndex` is a column heading, but attempts to address a column by name produce exceptions.

```
df2['timeIndex']
# KeyError: 'timeIndex'

df2['isZero']
# KeyError: 'isZero'
```

I am looking for this result.

```
df2 

     timeIndex    isZero
0    1    1
1    2    0

df2['isZero']

0    1
1    0
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Method 1:**

use the argument `as_index = False` in your `groupby`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['timeIndex'], as_index=False)['isZero'].sum()

>>> df2
   timeIndex  isZero
0          1       1
1          2       0

>>> df2['isZero']
0    1
1    0
Name: isZero, dtype: int64
```

**Method 2:**

You can use `to_frame` with your desired column name and then `reset_index`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['timeIndex'])['isZero'].sum().to_frame('isZero').reset_index()

>>> df2
   timeIndex  isZero
0          1       1
1          2       0

>>> df2['isZero']
0    1
1    0
Name: isZero, dtype: int64
```